# Video in Github markdown not displaying in Chrome but works perfectly fine in Safari

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I want to add a video in my github portfolio, I do it by using

```
![](/files/recording.mp4)
```

(The mp4 file is saved in *files* folder)

However, the video was not being displayed in Chrome/Edge, but works fine in Safari.
The I tried directly dragging the video into the markdown, it was showing in the preview mode, but would display only a link in all the browsers.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

add this theme [hugo-video](https://github.com/martignoni/hugo-video)

get the theme

```bash
git submodule add https://github.com/martignoni/hugo-video.git themes/hugo-video
```

edit config.yml

```
theme: ["hugo-video", "my-theme"]
```

use it

```
{{< video src="sample-video.mp4" >}}
```

OR

try this [blog](https://dev.to/hi_artem/add-a-video-to-your-hugo-website-104)

its adding a shorthand `video` in hugo in `layouts/shorthand/video.html`
which makes use of JS video player library [clappr](https://github.com/clappr/clappr) to create a player given the URL of the video file

layouts/shorthand/video.html

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="player-wrapper"></div>
</div>

<script 
type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@clappr/player@latest/dist/clappr.min.js"
>
</script>

<script>
    var playerElement = document.getElementById("player-wrapper");

    var player = new Clappr.Player({
        source: {{ .Get 0 }},
        
        mute: true,
        height: 360,
        width: 640
    });

    player.attachTo(playerElement);  
</script>
```

then in your post where you need the video you can do

```
this is my video
{{< video "video.mp4" "my-5" >}}
```

both get the task done in similar fashion! former uses a video html tag and is clean in my opinion, latter uses a JS library and feels like making a little bit of mess.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @philipmathieu. Usually github will load a video preview. There are times however, specially after uploading a video, that I would only get text, and no video preview, like this:

```
your_project/assets/28913157/bc4e9639-43a5-4937-bb64-ffa0c9f64a21
```

To force video preview put this on your markdown file.

```
<video src='your_project/assets/28913157/bc4e9639-43a5-4937-bb64-ffa0c9f64a21' />
```

Answer (score -1):

Because the Markdown specification varies from platform to platform, video support can be inconsistent. The simplest solution is to use an HTML video tag instead:

```
<video src='/files/recording.mp4' />
```

This has the added benefit of allowing you to set the styling with HTML/CSS.